# Error with the version of the database in liferay 7

Tags: mysql, liferay, liferay-7

I work with Eclipse and I want to use the version 7 of Liferay but when  I run my Tomcat server I have an error with MySQL.

> Please upgrade to at least MySQL 5.6.4. The portal no longer supports older versions of MySQL

Like this the problem is pretty obvious but my SQL version is already 5.7.19

I have check my driver of MySQL in preference->data management->connectivity->driver definition and my MySQL JDBC Driver is 5.1

I want to know if someone already had this issue and know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/events/StartupAction.java#L175) is how the version gets validated, and [this](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/7.0/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/dao/db/BaseDB.java#L198) is how the version string gets constructed. I'd say: Please make extra extra *extra* sure that you are addressing the mysql server that you intend to address:

You can check your mysql version from the mysql command line client by executing `select version();`. Get your credentials and database URL from Liferay's portal-ext.properties or your appserver's connection pool configuration, depending on where you configured it.